# SQL query to get totals

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a table that consists of two columns: question and answer. I currently use this query to get totals for answers:

```
SELECT *, count(answer) AS total
FROM survey_data
GROUP BY answer (originally said: question)
ORDER BY `total` DESC
```

It tells me how often an answer has occurred, which is what I want, however I found that some questions had the same answer. This query does not take that in account. How can I refine this query so it will also show the different questions with the same answer, so I know which total belongs to which question.

Thanks,
Ryan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use QUESTION in the SELECT, instead of *.  This makes it clearer what the total relates to

```
SELECT question, count(answer) AS total
FROM survey_data
GROUP BY question
ORDER BY `total` DESC
```

The query **does not** and **cannot** "tell you how often an answer has occurred" - because you are not grouping by answer. The only reason "answer" shows up in the result is because you *abused* MySQL's mixing of aggregate (grouped column) and non-aggregate column in the SELECT clause via `*` (so you are showing the question, and for each question, a ***completely arbitrary*** answer.

If you need to know how many times an answer occurs, you need to group by answer instead.

```
SELECT answer, count(answer) AS total
FROM survey_data
GROUP BY answer
ORDER BY `total` DESC
```

And if you needed both in the same query (which makes no sense - just use two queries one after the other), then a convoluted way *(not tested)*

```
SELECT 'question' as type, question, count(answer) AS total
FROM survey_data
GROUP BY question
UNION ALL
SELECT 'answer' as type, answer, count(answer) AS total
FROM survey_data
GROUP BY answer
ORDER BY type, `total` DESC
```

---

### EDIT

This may be what you are after, which assumes the table is not normalised and that each answer/question combination can occur many times

```
SELECT answer, question, count(*) AS total
FROM survey_data
GROUP BY answer, question
ORDER BY `total` DESC
```

Comment: Sorry, where it said 'question' in my sample, that was actually 'answer' ... I mistyped.

Comment: The "union" query? Because when I ran it, it gave me this:
answer  The Magic House  1248
answer  Scholarshop  1197
answer  Alpine Shop  1145
But I don't know which question this answers belong to?

Comment: @Ryan / please see the last query added to the answer

Comment: That makes sense and works! Thanks so much for your time. I was close :)